Required sample size for logistic regression?
Early stage PhD candidate trying to suss out project specifics. Currently trying to calculate the sample size required for a binomial logistic regression with one IV and one DV, alpha level 0.05 and power of 0.8. My usual go-to of G*Power is asking for a bunch of figures that I'm unsure of, and I can't seem to find a formula online to do this calculation myself.

Hi @Annie, welcome to CV! "My usual go-to of G*Power is asking for a bunch of figures that I'm unsure of" - what are these? If you could explain this, and a bit more about the context, and what you're trying to test, that will help us help you.

I'm not going to fend for the G*Power UI (nor any other), but here is an example of how this is implemented in SAS; because power calculation means solving for a single unknown there simply is quite a lot you do have to specify in such cases. Assumptions are rarely more than approximately true however (and even less often verifiably so), so it's usually a good idea to investigate a range of plausible parameters.

Not to be unhelpful but IMO this is explained pretty well in the G*Power manual: https://www.psychologie.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Fakultaeten/Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche_Fakultaet/Psychologie/AAP/gpower/GPowerManual.pdf, p. 70 onwards.
